# Display explicit plus sign in pgfplots axis

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a more elegant way than mine to display explicit plus signs for positive values on the axis of a pgfplots graph?

Currently I'm doing

```
    xtick={-3,-2,...,+3},
    xticklabels={-3,-2,-1,0,+1,+2,+3},
```

but thats not perfect as I would have to update xticklabels if I want to change the graph.

Comment: `xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/showpos=true}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the `print sign` option to the `pgf/number format`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,print sign}]
   \addplot coordinates {(-2,1) (-1,2) (2,3) (3,2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you don't want the sign on the zero, then you can process that case separately as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,print sign},
    xticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=0pt$0$\else\axisdefaultticklabel\fi}]
   \addplot coordinates {(-2,1) (-1,2) (2,3) (3,2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample without sign on zero]

`\axisdefaultticklabel` is `$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$`, so if you wanted `0` printed with the same number styling as the other ticks but without the sign you could replace `$0$` with

```
$\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign=false]{\tick}$
```

in the above code.

Comment: And is it possible to *not* show a plus sign for zero?

Comment: Yes - extra code example added.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll go and try to understand that and do it by myself the next time.